# DevStack -- Unable to lauch instance due to nova-rootwrap

Tags: openstack, devstack

Message
    Remote error: ProcessExecutionError Unexpected error while running command. Command: sudo nova-rootwrap /etc/nova/rootwrap.conf env CONFIG_FILE=["/etc/nova/nova.conf"] NETWORK_ID=1 dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --conf-file= --pid-file=/opt/stac

Code
    500

Details

```
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 293, in decorated_function return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2003, in run_instance do_run_instance() File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/openstack/common/lockutils.py", line 249, in inner return f(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2002, in do_run_instance legacy_bdm_in_spec) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1150, in _run_instance notify("error", fault=e) # notify that build failed File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 68, in __exit__ six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1134, in _run_instance instance, image_meta, legacy_bdm_in_spec) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1287, in _build_instance filter_properties, bdms, legacy_bdm_in_spec) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1333, in _reschedule_or_error self._log_original_error(exc_info, instance_uuid) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 68, in __exit__ six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1328, in _reschedule_or_error bdms, requested_networks) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2055, in _shutdown_instance self._try_deallocate_network(context, instance, requested_networks) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2014, in _try_deallocate_network self._set_instance_error_state(context, instance['uuid']) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 68, in __exit__ six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2009, in _try_deallocate_network self._deallocate_network(context, instance, requested_networks) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1708, in _deallocate_network context, instance, requested_networks=requested_networks) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/network/api.py", line 94, in wrapped return func(self, context, *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/network/api.py", line 318, in deallocate_for_instance requested_networks=requested_networks) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/network/rpcapi.py", line 190, in deallocate_for_instance return cctxt.call(ctxt, 'deallocate_for_instance', **kwargs) File "/opt/stack/oslo.messaging/oslo/messaging/rpc/client.py", line 361, in call return self.prepare().call(ctxt, method, **kwargs) File "/opt/stack/oslo.messaging/oslo/messaging/rpc/client.py", line 150, in call wait_for_reply=True, timeout=timeout) File "/opt/stack/oslo.messaging/oslo/messaging/transport.py", line 90, in _send timeout=timeout) File "/opt/stack/oslo.messaging/oslo/messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 409, in send return self._send(target, ctxt, message, wait_for_reply, timeout) File "/opt/stack/oslo.messaging/oslo/messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 402, in _send raise result
```

---

I am not able to figure out the problem. Please help!

Comment: I got the same problem~

Answer (score 0):

I made change in localrc file as below and run stack.sh script again, it worked:

stack@ubuntu:~/devstack$ cat localrc

```
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.1.224/27
FIXED_RANGE=10.11.12.0/24
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256
ADMIN_PASSWORD=root123
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root123
RABBIT_PASSWORD=root123
SERVICE_PASSWORD=root123
FORCE=yes
SERVICE_TOKEN=root123
LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.1.224/27
FIXED_RANGE=10.11.12.0/24
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256
FLAT_INTERFACE=eth0
```

stack@ubuntu:~/devstack$